# Python: is isalnum() the same as isalpha with isdigit?

Tags: python, string

Is there a way to concretely verify this? I tried to solve a coding question but it seems one of the test cases (not revealed to me) takes this as wrong. In what kinds of cases does this fail to be true?

Comment: yes, by finding python source code.

Comment: For reference, [`isalnum()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.5/Objects/bytes_methods.c#L71)

Comment: What do you mean by *"isalpha with isdigit"*? Your question is not precise enough.

Comment: I mean in code form "k.isalpha() or k.isdigit()" is equivalent to k.isalnum()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are cases when both `isalpha` and `isdigit` returns `False`, but `isalnum` returns `True`. So `isalnum` is not just a combination of the other two.

```
>>> 'a1'.isalpha(), 'a1'.isdigit(), 'a1'.isalnum()
(False, False, True)
```

Answer (score 4):

From the documentation of Python 3:

> `str.isalnum()`
>   *Return true if all characters in the string are alphanumeric and there is at least one character, false otherwise. A character c is alphanumeric if one the following returns True: c.isalpha(), c.isdecimal(), c.isdigit(), or c.isnumeric().*

So it is not the same as `isalpha()` nor `isdigit()`.

Answer (score 1):

**According to Python 2.7 Documentation**

> [str.**isalnum()**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalnum) 
>                 Return true if all characters in the string are alphanumeric and there is at least one character, false otherwise.

**According to Python 3.6.6 Documentation**

> [str.**isalnum()**](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalnum) 
>                 Return true if all characters in the string are alphanumeric and there is at least one character, false otherwise. A character `c` is alphanumeric if one of the following returns `True`: `c.isalpha()`, `c.isdecimal()`, `c.isdigit()`, or `c.isnumeric()`.

Here are few tests for `isalnum()` in python v3.6.6

```
>>> "alpha".isalnum()
True
>>> "alpha10".isalnum()
True
>>> "alpha%&@".isalnum()
False
>>> "alpha %&@".isalnum()
False
>>> "alpha with space".isalnum()
False
```

In first test `"alpha".isalnum()` returns `True`

And in `isalpha()` test, results are like this:

```
>>> "alpha".isalpha()
True
>>> "alpha10".isalpha()
False
>>> "alpha%&@".isalpha()
False
>>> "alpha %&@".isalpha()
False
>>> "alpha with space".isalpha()
False
```

So the problem is that `isalnum()` and `isalpha()` both returns `True` when a string contains only characters

```
>>> "alpha".isalnum()
True
>>> "alpha".isalpha()
True
```