# Difference between isalnum and isdigit

Tags: python

```
a = '123'
a.isalnum() retruns True
a.isdigit() also returns True
```

In string 'a' there are no characters available how does isalnum returns true.
How does isalnum works when the string contains only digits.

Comment: alnum : alpha OR numerical.

Comment: `alnum` stands for "alpha-numeric". `123` only has numeric characters.

Comment: Have you checked docs.python.org?

Comment: you mean `isalpha` ?

Comment: Maybe you need to search before ask :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37762230/python-is-isalnum-the-same-as-isalpha-with-isdigit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: is isalnum() the same as isalpha with isdigit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37762230/python-is-isalnum-the-same-as-isalpha-with-isdigit)

Answer (score 2):

> The method isdigit() checks whether the string consists of digits
>   only.

See: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_isdigit.htm

> The method isalnum() checks whether the string consists of
>   alphanumeric characters.

See: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_isalnum.htm

Both return true, because for isdigit(), the string contains purely digits.
For isalnum(), all characters are either alpha or numeric.